# jQuery get object moused over

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery

I have this code:

```
    $('*').mouseover(function() {
        $('#log').text($('*').id);
    });
```

When you mouse over any element on the page, I want `#log` to have the id of that element. Obviously the code above doesn't work... How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('*').mouseover(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('id'))
});
```

In almost all jQuery callbacks, "this" is the object on which the callback is being executed.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('*').mouseover(function() {
    $('#log').text($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use event.target

```
var $log = $("#log");
$('*').mouseover(function(event) {
    $log.text($(event.target).attr('id'));
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```